# C# mvc async function typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, function, asynchronous, model-view-controller

I have two function in controller. One return Json and second reutrn some View.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetBackend(int userid, int city, int address)
{
    //some code communication with backend
     reutrn Json("Ok");
}


public ActionResult DoView(int userid, int city, int address)
{
     //some code
     return PartialView("~/View/View1.cshtml");
}
```

Function DoView to correctly open need some date from backend so function GetBackend need to finish before function DoView will start.

I have 3 function in typescript:

```
public UserClick()
{
   var userid = 1;
   var city = London;
   var address = Street 1;
   this.DoSomeThing1(userid, city, address);
   this.DoSomeThing2(userid, city, address);
}

public DoSomeThing1(userid, city, address)
{
   var data = JSON.stringify({
   "userId": userid,
   "city": city,
   "address" address
    });

   serviceBase.Service("Controller","GetBackend", data)
}

public DomSomeThing2(userid, city, address)
{

   var data = JSON.stringify({
   "userId": userid,
   "city": city,
   "address" address
    });

    serviceBase.Service("Controller","DoView", data)
}
```

I call function UserClick() from typescript. How Can i do that function in DoSomeThing2() will start when function DoSomeThing1() will be completed?

I dont know how to do that i will be sure that View will open correctly with all date from function GetBackend.

Code serviceBase

```
public Service(controller: string , action: string, data: string) {
    if (typeof controller != "string" || typeof action != "string"){
       throw new Error("Error");
    }
    return $ajax.({
        url: '/' + controller + '/' + action,
        method: "post",
        contentType: 'appliaction/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data
    })
}
```

I do this code in typescript

```
  this.DoSomeThing1(userid, city, address)
       .done(this.DoSomeThing2(userid, city, address));
```

I have in code red underline

TS2345: Comment: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TypeOrArray<CallbackBase<any, SuccessTextStatus, jqXHR, never>>'

Comment: show your code in `serviceBase.Service`

Comment: I add in post .

Comment: you need to learn about async/await in javascript. Then the ajax calls must be wrapped in promises that you can await its completion, before start the next call.

Comment: Can You write some example?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the 2nd function after the 1st function by doing this:

```
public DoSomeThing1(userid, city, address)
{
   var data = JSON.stringify({
   "userId": userid,
   "city": city,
   "address" address
    });

   return serviceBase.Service("Controller","GetBackend", data)
}
```

```
   this.DoSomeThing1(userid, city, address)
       .done(this.DoSomeThing2(userid, city, address));
```

or

```
   this.DoSomeThing1(userid, city, address)
       .done(function(response){
          console.log(response);
          this.DoSomeThing2(userid, city, address);
          // do another here...
    
        });
```

Comment: What will be function(response) in this case?

Comment: response is what your backend returns.

Comment: I have return Json('Ok'), Can i know in typescript that the code in controller is after this return?

Comment: `console.log(response)`

Comment: I mean how can I take this 'ok' to response in typescript? (I mean send it to typescript)

Comment: that is already sent. Did you try the code?

Comment: Yes, i try but this.DoSomeThing2(userid, city, address) is omitted. Just do only DoSomeThing1(userid, city, address)

Comment: You need to show what you did that is not working, instead of looking for answers directly.

Comment: I edit question and add it now. Mb i need to return this Json('Ok') to some variable in typescript and when the variable != null then this.DoSomeThing2(userid, city, address).
What do You think about it?

Comment: In your `DoSomeThing1` method, did you modify it to `return serviceBase.Service("Controller","GetBackend", data)`?

Comment: You need to learn `Promise` and `Deferred`.
The `.done(function(response){` means your api returns 200 successful, and whatever your Api returns should be in the variable `response` in this case. So if you `console.log(response)` you should see the `Ok`.
 To catch the error use `.fail(function(error){`

Comment: Yes, i add return to function DoSomeThing1